# Select first record in database

Tags: sql, sql-server

Forgive me if I'm not explaining this properly. But I have the following records

```
yearID    franchID    name
---------------------------
1966      ATL         Atlanta Braves
1883      ATL         Boston Beaneaters
1883      PHI         Philadelphia Quakers
1936      ATL         Boston Bees
1993      PHI         Philadelphia Phillies
```

But I want the starting year and original name of the franchise, so the output should look like this:

```
StartYear    franchI    name
--------------------------------
1883         ATL        Boston Beaneaters
1883         PHI        Philadelphia Quakers
```

The SQL I have right now is this:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(yearID) as StartYear, franchID, name
FROM dbo.LahmanTeams
GROUP BY franchID, name;
```

That gives me the first output, but I'd like to get the original franchise name.

Comment: Are you familiar with window functions like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...)`? In your case, you would partition by franchid and order by year then select only those whose row number = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a CTE (no reason for a join)

```
CREATE Table #LahmanTeams
(   yearID  INT,
    franchID varchar(255),
    [name] varchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO #LahmanTeams VALUES (1966, 'ATL', 'Atlanta Braves')
INSERT INTO #LahmanTeams VALUES (1883, 'ATL', 'Boston Beaneaters')
INSERT INTO #LahmanTeams VALUES (1883, 'PHI', 'Philadelphia Quakers')
INSERT INTO #LahmanTeams VALUES (1936, 'ATL', 'Boston Bees')
INSERT INTO #LahmanTeams VALUES (1993, 'PHI', 'Philadelphia Phillies');

WITH teams AS
(
SELECT 
   yearID, franchID, name,                 Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY franchid 
                    ORDER BY yearid asc) AS rn 

FROM #LahmanTeams
GROUP BY franchID, name, yearID
)
SELECT * from teams where rn = 1
```

OUTPUT:

```
1883    ATL Boston Beaneaters       1
1883    PHI Philadelphia Quakers    1
```

Comment: We have a winner!

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the WITH TIES clause in concert with Row_Number()

**Example**

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From  dbo.LahmanTeams
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By franchID  Order By yearID  )
```

Comment: Never thought of that - I like it

Comment: Neither did I until the first time I saw it done  :)

Comment: I will have to try it on a large db where I do something similar to see which performs better.

Comment: @Kevin You should see the same performance as the CTE approach.   Let me know.  Thx.

Comment: At least with the sample data in the question and no indexes or anything, the plans for this and the regular way of doing it (subquery with RN and `where RN = 1`) are similar except that this one does seems to do an additional sort (though it's not particularly costly with the small amount of data involved here). They both need to do one sort for the window function, but TOP 1 sorts again whereas `where RN = 1` is just a filter.

Comment: @ZLK Against a table of 508,778 records returning 1,537 records the CTE was 193ms and the WITH TIES 206ms.  Yes the CTE is faster, but on the plus no extra field to contend with.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY franchID ORDER BY yearID) [RowNo],  yearID , franchID, name
    FROM dbo.LahmanTeams
)
SELECT A.yearID [StartYear], A.franchID, A.name
FROM
    dbo.LahmanTeams A
INNER JOIN
    CTE A
    ON A.franchID = B.franchID
    AND A.yearID = B.yearID
WHERE
    B.RowNo = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think everybody's over thinking this. Your original effort was almost there, but for the changing team names.

First, get the minimum year for each franchise ID (that's the subquery), then join that to the full table to get the rest of the columns for that entry (and that's the outer query).

```
declare @LahmanTeams table (
yearID int,
franchID char(3),
name varchar(50));

insert @LahmanTeams
values
(1966,'ATL','Atlanta Braves')
,(1883,'ATL','Boston Beaneaters')
,(1883,'PHI','Philadelphia Quakers')
,(1936,'ATL','Boston Bees')
,(1993,'PHI','Philadelphia Phillies');

SELECT 
    t.*
FROM @LahmanTeams AS t
JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            franchID,
            MIN(yearID) as yearID
        FROM 
            @LahmanTeams 
        GROUP BY 
            franchID
    ) AS s
        ON s.franchID = t.franchID
        AND s.yearID = t.yearID
```

Results:

```
+--------+----------+----------------------+
| yearID | franchID |         name         |
+--------+----------+----------------------+
|   1883 | ATL      | Boston Beaneaters    |
|   1883 | PHI      | Philadelphia Quakers |
+--------+----------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then ordinary `ORDER BY` would suffice:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(yearID) as StartYear, franchID, name
FROM dbo.LahmanTeams
GROUP BY franchID, name
ORDER BY StartYear;
```

Comment: It normally would, but I want just the first Franchise Name, not the other incarnations